# Hidden content when position fixed and top>0

Tags: css, offset, fixed

[Here is my example](http://jsfiddle.net/AKL35/573/) if you try to scroll down you will only get some content, and you can't view the last lines. How I might fix this?

```
div#scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
}
```

I need:

- Fixed div;
- Offset of some value from the top;

Thanks

Comment: it's you're OK with HTML5 compliant browsers `height: calc(100% - 100px);` http://jsfiddle.net/AKL35/574/

Comment: Oh, that's a hacky way. Anything else?

Comment: `position:fixed; top:100px; bottom:0; overflow:auto;` - http://jsfiddle.net/AKL35/578/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
div#scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/a8dxhLra/

Comment: Thanks, this works (: my project is a lot more complex but this enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be using some kind of a flexible layout to adjust the height inside the fixed element. Here's a solution using `display: table`.

It creates a pseudo `100px` height row, that pushes the `#scrollable` div down, making it fill the remaining space on the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/AKL35/581/

```
#fixed-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#fixed-wrapper:before {
    display: table-row;
    content: "";
    height: 100px;
}

div#scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```